# How to stop RSpec test run to send a Twilio text message?

Tags: ruby, rspec, twilio

How do you prevent Rspec from triggering a text message while running a test? I only want a text message to be sent via IRB.

This is the message obtained from the test running the send_sms method :

```
<Twilio::REST::Message @path=/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC818.....a16c/Messages/SM8....6cd>
```

Here is the `#send_sms` method:

```
def send_sms
  @account_sid = 'AC818...16c'
  @auth_token  = 'c128...431'
  @from_number = '+44...18'
  @to_number   = '+44...31'
  @client      = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
  @account     = @client.account
  @sms         = @account.messages.create(
    from: @from_number,
    to:   @to_number,
    body: "Thank you! Your order was placed and will be delivered."
  )
  p @sms
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your specs, it's hard to tell you what to change, but you'll need to stub/mock out the `send_sms` method, so a fake method is called.

The [`rspec-mocks`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) gem is where these live, and the documentation is on that link.

Basically, you'll do something like:

```
let(:something) { no_clue_what_you_have }

before do
  expect(something).to receive(:send_sms)
end

it 'sends an SMS message' do
  something.again_we_have_no_idea_what_you_are_doing
end
```

Best to supply as much code as you can when asking for help!  But hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd also suggest including something like WebMock (https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) that can stop external APIs being called during tests, encouraging you to mock them out like this.